# Ajax Request Chinese Character return '?'

Tags: jquery, node.js, character-encoding

I run a scrape site using nodejs to get the articles, I want to load Chinese website using XMLHttpRequest and the site is using this meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gbk" />
```

and my site used charset UTF-8

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/html; charset=gbk');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
//DOM Processing
    $=cheerio.load(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

does anyone know what i have to set for the header ? I tried charset gbk / GB2312 also didn't work. Any help will be great. 
Thanks

Comment: what happens if you just remove this meta field?

Comment: @YuduBan same, nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using: https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest

In "Known Issues / Missing Features":
Local file access may have unexpected results for non-UTF8 files

So I think this cannot be solved by node-XMLHttpRequest.

Here is my solution for scrape site using gbk, hope this is useful for you.

```
const rp = require('request-promise')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const iconv = require('iconv-lite')

const options = {
    url: `http://www.duchang.org/`,
    transform: function (body) {
        let html = iconv.decode(body, 'gbk')
        return cheerio.load(html)
    },
    encoding: null
}
rp(options)
    .then(($) => {
        // 首页头条
        console.log($)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        throw Error(err)
    })
```

Comment: Wow !! I've been looking this for 2 days
Thanks, it working well !!